# Particular example of a quadratic extension of a nonunital ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

I want to construct a concrete non-unital ring $R$ with the following properties:

1. $R$ is a noncommutative non-unital ring with a right unite $r$ i.e $t.r=t$ for any $t\in R$.
2. $S\subset R$ is a commutative subring (with unit $r$) and the inclusion $S\subset R$ has a section $f: R\rightarrow S$ in the category of nonunital rings sending right unit $r$ to the unit $r$.
3. The kernel of $f$, the ideal $I$ has the property : the multiplication of any two elements of $I$ is equal to zero. And the inclusion $I\subset R$ has a section in the category of nonunital rings
4. For any element $s\in S$ and any element $i\in I$ we have $s.i=0$

Is there such triple $(R,S,I)$ verifying all condition 1-4 such that $R$ is non unital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently by "section" you mean "left inverse". Usually this word means "right inverse".

No. Let $g:R\to I$ be that left inverse to the inclusion. Since it is a (non-unital) ring map, and since products in $I$ are zero, and since $I$ is an ideal in $R$, we have $0=g(i)g(s)=g(is)=is$ for every $s\in S$ and $i\in I$. Therefore the ring $R$ is simply the ring $S\oplus I$ that we get from the commutative ring $S$ and the abelian group $I$ by writing $R=S\oplus I$ and letting $si$, $is$, and $i_1i_2$ be $0$. It is commutative and unital.

Comment: But why $i.s$ has to be equal to 0? If it is 0 I agree that R has to be commutative. Certainly i missing a part of your argument, why we are left with this only possibility ?

Comment: $is$ has to be zero, because $g(is)=0$ and $is=g(is)$. $is=g(is)$ because and $is\in I$ $g$ is a left inverse of the inclusion $I\to R$. $g(is)$ is the product of $g(i)$ and $g(s)$, two elements of $I$.